# Can you enable and disable an azure timer trigger over http?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I am having an amusing time creating a cloud function that presses an IOT physical button every 4 minutes, but I want to be able to turn the service on and off by just clicking a button in a web browser.

From what I can tell, my azure timer trigger needs to be enabled to start it and disabled to stop it. I can do that manually. I can see how to do that with the azure cli. What I want to know is if I can do it via GETs or POSTs with some set of limited azure credentials that are only allowed privileges on this one thing. Has anyone looked into this?

Comment: Yes, you can search in this documents, its the Api to manage resources in Azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/

Comment: You can create a service principal,grant it with the permission to operate your function only.Using this service principal to get access token to call APIs could meet your requirement

Comment: These were useful comments, and I made some progress, but I kept breaking the functions when I tried to update the appsettings. I will try the answer below, which seems to give more details about how to accomplish the update. Thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop and start Azure function app via rest API, you can implement it by adding `AzureWebJobs.<FUNCTION_NAME>.Disabled=true` in app settings. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function).

Regarding how to implement it, we can call API  [`Update Application Settings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateapplicationsettings) to add the setting. But please note that after calling the API, it will replace the origin settings. So we need to call API [`List Application Settings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listapplicationsettings) to get the origin settings then call update API with these settings.

Besides if you want to control the permissions, you can create a [custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles). The role should have permissions **Microsoft.Web/sites/config/Write** and **Microsoft.Web/sites/config/list/Action**.

For example

1. Create a custom role

a. create role definition file `function.json`

```
{
  "Name": "function",
  "IsCustom": true,
  "Description": "",
  "Actions": [
       "Microsoft.Web/sites/config/Write",
       "Microsoft.Web/sites/config/list/Action"     
  ],
  "NotActions": [

  ],
  "AssignableScopes": [
    "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId1}",
    "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId2}"
  ]
}
```

b. create

```
az role definition create --role-definition ~/function.json
```

2. create a service priciapal and assign the custom role for the sp

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role "function"
```

3. [Call API to stop function](https://aster.cloud/2019/09/25/how-to-call-azure-rest-apis/)

a. get token

```
POST /<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type =client_credentials
&client_id=<sp appId>
d&client_secret=<sp password>&resource=https://management.azure.com/
```

b. list

```
POST /subscriptions/<>/resourceGroups/<group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<function app name>/config/appsettings/list?api-version=2019-08-01 HTTP/1.1
Host: management.azure.com
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

[image]

c. update

```
PUT /subscriptions/<>/resourceGroups/<group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<function app name>/config/appsettings?api-version=2019-08-01 HTTP/1.1
Host: management.azure.com
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Type: application/json

{

    "kind": "functionapp,linux or windows",
    "properties": {
        "AzureWebJobs.<FUNCTION_NAME>.Disabled": true,
        ... other settings you copy from above
    }

}
```

[image]
[image]